# PHP str_ireplace in libreoffice basic

Tags: php, libreoffice-basic

Does anybody know how to make function in Libreoffice basic like `str_ireplace` in PHP?
I want to use in my cell function.

```
str_ireplace(search - range of cells, replace - range of cells, text)
```

or at least `str_replace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made really simple function

```
Function Str_ireplace(Search As Variant, Replace As Variant, Source As String)

  Dim Result As String
  Dim StartPos As Long
  Dim CurrentPos As Long
  Dim CurrentSearch As String
  Dim CurrentReplace As String

  Result = ""

  For Row = Lbound( Search, 1 ) To Ubound( Search, 1 )
    For Col = LBound(Search, 2) To UBound(Search, 2)
        StartPos = 1
        CurrentPos = 1
        CurrentSearch = Search(Row, Col)
        CurrentReplace = Replace(Row, Col)
        Result = ""


        Do While CurrentPos <> 0
            CurrentPos = InStr(StartPos, Source, CurrentSearch)
            If CurrentPos <> 0 Then
                Result = Result + Mid(Source, StartPos, _
                CurrentPos - StartPos)
                Result = Result + CurrentReplace
                StartPos = CurrentPos + Len(CurrentSearch)
            Else
                Result = Result + Mid(Source, StartPos, Len(Source))
            End If                ' Position <> 0
        Loop
        Source = Result 
    Next 
  Next


  Str_ireplace = Result    
End Function
```

I used this as example: 
http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Strings_(Runtime_Library)

Answer (score 0):

try this

Syntax

**REPLACE("Text"; Position; Length; "NewText")**

Text refers to text of which a part will be replaced.

Position refers to the position within the text where the replacement will begin.

Length is the number of characters in Text to be replaced.

NewText refers to the text which replaces Text.

**Example**

```
=REPLACE("1234567";1;1;"444") returns "444234567". One character at position 1 is replaced by the complete NewText.
```

https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#Example_13

or

**SUBSTITUTE("Text"; "SearchText"; "NewText"; Occurrence)**

**Example**

=SUBSTITUTE("123123123";"3";"abc") returns 12abc12abc12abc.

=SUBSTITUTE("123123123";"3";"abc";2) returns 12312abc123.

https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#SUBSTITUTE

Comment: you cannot use array of search and array of replace values with this approach.